# Хорошо ВОСПИТАН: краткое причастие?

Tags: прилагательные, причастия

Правильно я понимаю, что в тексте:

> — Он будет **хорошо воспитан**, — успокоила маму фрекен Бок. — Не
>   беспокойтесь, у меня и дети быстро становятся шёлковыми.

слово *воспитан* — это краткое причастие в силу наличия перед ним *наречия образа действия хорошо*?

Answer (score 4):

Он будет хорошо воспитан - это **причастие**, обозначающее процессуальный признак, то есть признак как действие.

**А вот наречие "хорошо" - не причина, но индикатор того, что перед нами причастие,  а не отпричастное прилагательное.** Причастие "воспитан" обычно имеет **зависимые слова**, отвечающие на вопросы  "как, где, кем" (они переходят к причастию из глагольного словосочетания),  в то время как отпричастное прилагательное обычно находится **в однородных отношениях** с другим прилагательным и зависимых слов не имеет.

**Примеры**

Потом приказала моей матушке от своего имени поклониться и поблагодарить ее за то, что так **хорошо воспитывает** детей своих. [И. С. Тургенев. Отрывки из воспоминаний своих и чужих (1881)]

Как и весь его народ, он **хорошо воспитан** и привык уважать чужое мнение. [О. Э. Мандельштам. Батум (1923)]

Она была **хорошо воспитана** и умела скрывать свои истинные чувства.

Холостые вспомнили, что Наташа **хороша, воспитанна**, получает лучшее жалованье, ― и опечалились. [В. А. Соллогуб. Теменевская ярмарка (1845)]

Answer (score 0):

По идее - да, это причастие (есть признаки действия; Фрекен Бок его *воспитает*).